# How MySQL engine execute IN query?

Tags: mysql

I'm just want to know that how actually MySQL execute 'IN' Query.

For example,
I have a query in which i use 100 parameters in IN array, like:

```
SELECT  productName, price  FROM tbl_product WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,......,100) AND status = 'y';
```

now, how SQL engine perform this query??

is it will start any loop like

```
SELECT productName, price FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '1' AND status = 'y';

SELECT productName, price FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '2' AND status = 'y';

SELECT productName, price FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '3' AND status = 'y';

SELECT productName, price FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '4' AND status = 'y';
.........
........
......
SELECT productName, price FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '98' AND status = 'y';

SELECT productName, price FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '99' AND status = 'y';

SELECT productName, price FROM tbl_product WHERE id = '100' AND status = 'y';
```

OR

Just fetch from 1 query like

```
SELECT productName, price FROM tbl_product WHERE (id = '1' OR id = '2' OR id = '3' OR id = '4' OR id = '5' .......... OR id = '99' OR id = '100') AND status = 'y';
```

Comment: `in` will be executed the same way as `or` (or `= any`) is.